# How does Linear Recursion work?

Tags: java, recursion

I have written a java program to add elements in an array using Linear Recursion. The output obtained is not as expected. Can anyone point what is wrong with this program?

```
public class TestSum {

    public int count = 0;


    public int sum(int[] a){

        count++;

        if(a.length == count){
            return a[count -1];
        }

        return sum(a) + a[count -1] ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {1,2,3};

        int val = new TestSum().sum(a);
        System.out.println(val);
    }

}
```

I am expecting the output as 6 but obtained is **9**. What is wrong?

Strangely if I change the order of addition i.e. `return a[count -1] + sum(a);` then it gives output as **6**.

Comment: "Strangely if I change the order of addition i.e. return a[count -1] + sum(a); then it gives output as 6." Why do you find that strange?

Comment: I find it strange as the output changes only by changing the order of addition. I mean 2 +3 is same as 3 + 2. I am definite that my understanding about recursion is wrong and trying to figure out the same.

Comment: But you are not adding constants here. `sum(a)` changes the value of `count`, and thus changes `a[count-1]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, recursive programs that are not re-entrant (i.e. relying on external state) are suspicious. In your particular case `count` will change between invocations of `sum`, making the behavior hard to trace, and ultimately resulting in the error that you observe.

You should pass the index along with the array to make it work:

```
// The actual implementation passes the starting index
private static int sum(int[] a, int start){
    if(a.length == start){
        return 0;
    }
    return sum(a, start+1) + a[start];
}
// Make sure the method can be called with an array argument alone
public static int sum(int[] a) {
    return sum(a, 0);
}
```

Unlike an implementation that increments the count external to the method, this implementation can be called concurrently on multiple threads without breaking.

Comment: Agree with your answer but still did not get why is it error prone when count declared outside?

Comment: @user001 Because you cannot freely reference `count` without thinking how it would be modified by your own method's recursive invocation. The value of `count-1` on lines `return a[count -1];` and `return sum(a) + a[count -1]` are different, because there's a call to `sum(a)` in between them. This is the kind of things you need to watch out for when you keep invocation state external to your method.